# Slow formatting in QTextEdit

Tags: qt

For my custom editor for a scripting language I would like to format the text in a QTextEdit.
I use my custom scanner to create tokens from the text in the text edit and then want to highlight certain tokens:

```
void MainWindow::highlightTokens(const QList<VJassToken> &tokens) {
    // TODO this method is slow as hell! Improve its speed!
    qDebug() << "Beginning highlighting tokens with tokens size:" << tokens.size();
    QElapsedTimer timer;
    timer.start();

    // make sure no slots are triggered by this to prevent endless recursions
    disconnect(ui->textEdit, &QTextEdit::textChanged, this, &MainWindow::restartTimer);

    QTextCharFormat fmtNormal;
    fmtNormal.setBackground(Qt::white);
    fmtNormal.setFontWeight(QFont::Normal);

    QTextCursor cursor(ui->textEdit->document());
    // start at the beginning of the document
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);

    int line = 0;
    int column = 0;

    for (const VJassToken &token : tokens) {
        // only hightlight certain tokens at all
        if (token.getType() != VJassToken::WhiteSpace && token.getType() != VJassToken::LineBreak) {
            // move to token
            int lines = token.getLine() - line;
            int columns = 0;

            if (lines > 0) {
                cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfLine, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
                cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Down, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor, lines);
                column = token.getColumn();
                columns = token.getColumn();
                cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextCharacter, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor, columns);
                //qDebug() << "Moving to the start of the line";
                //qDebug() << "Moving down" << lines << "lines.";
            } else {
                columns = token.getColumn() - column;
                cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextCharacter, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor, columns);
                //qDebug() << "Moving to the right" << column << "columns.";
            }

            //qDebug() << "After moving selection to token to format normal, selection start:" << cursor.selectionStart() << "and selection end" << cursor.selectionEnd();
            if (lines > 0 || columns > 0) {
                // format normal until here since it might be some space without any tokens
                cursor.setCharFormat(fmtNormal);
                cursor.setPosition(cursor.position(), QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
            }

            //qDebug() << "After moving selection to token, selection start:" << cursor.selectionStart() << "and selection end" << cursor.selectionEnd();

            // specify the format for the token itself
            QTextCharFormat fmt;

            // formats are taken from https://github.com/tdauth/syntaxhighlightings/blob/master/Kate/vjass.xml
            if (token.isValidKeyword()) {
                fmt.setForeground(Qt::black);
                fmt.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
            } else if (token.getType() == VJassToken::Comment) {
                fmt.setForeground(Qt::gray);
                fmt.setFontItalic(true);
            } else if (token.getType() == VJassToken::BooleanLiteral) {
                fmt.setForeground(Qt::blue);
            } else if (token.getType() == VJassToken::RawCodeLiteral || token.getType() == VJassToken::IntegerLiteral || token.getType() == VJassToken::RealLiteral) {
                fmt.setForeground(Qt::darkYellow);
            } else if (token.getType() == VJassToken::Text) {
                // Make a quick check for the symbol from hash sets of standard types and functions so we have these highlighted even without syntax checking
                if (token.isCommonJType()) {
                    fmt.setForeground(Qt::blue);
                } else if (token.isCommonJNative()) {
                    fmt.setForeground(QColor(0xba55d3));
                    fmt.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
                } else if (token.isCommonJConstant()) {
                    fmt.setForeground(QColor(0xff7f50));
                    fmt.setFontItalic(true);
                } else {
                    fmt = fmtNormal;
                }
            } else {
                fmt = fmtNormal;
            }

            //qDebug() << "Before selection start:" << cursor.selectionStart() << "and selection end" << cursor.selectionEnd();

            // move to the token's end but keep the selection and format it
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextCharacter, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor, token.getValueLength());
            cursor.setCharFormat(fmt);
            // move anchor to the end
            cursor.setPosition(cursor.position(), QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);

            //qDebug() << "Token:" << token.getValue() << "with line:" << token.getLine() << " and column:" << token.getColumn() << "and token length:" << token.getValue().length();
            //qDebug() << "After selection start:" << cursor.selectionStart() << "and selection end" << cursor.selectionEnd();

            // TODO set properly if the token contains line breaks
            // update current line and column
            line = token.getLine();
            column = token.getColumn() + token.getValue().length();
        }
    }

    // reset formatting for upcoming text
    ui->textEdit->setCurrentCharFormat(fmtNormal);

    connect(ui->textEdit, &QTextEdit::textChanged, this, &MainWindow::restartTimer);

    qDebug() << "Ending highlighting tokens with tokens size:" << tokens.size() << "and elapsed time" << timer.elapsed() << "ms and in seconds" << (timer.elapsed() / 1000) << "and in minutes" << (timer.elapsed() / (1000 * 60));
}
```

As you can see I go through all of my tokens with columns and lines and move the cursor to format the text. I also format text which is no token at all/some regular text since it could be formatted from previous runs. Maybe there is a way to clear the formatting before in a faster way?
I am not sure either if the moving cursor approach is slowing it down.

When I add a big file which has like 4197 lines I get the following output:

```
Ending highlighting tokens with tokens size: 46846 and elapsed time 79031 ms and in seconds 79 and in minutes 1
```

Hence, it takes over a minute to highlight everything. I expect Qt to store the formatting settings but only format it in one single paint run. One idea might be to only highlight the characters visible in the viewport of the text edit instead of the whole document.

edit:
Just found this https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setExtraSelections and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html Maybe these are a bit faster than moving the cursor and formatting it.

Comment: Just two tips for optimisation which come to my mind: How about using `QPlainTextEdit` instead of `QTextEdit`? And maybe it would be good to use `QSignalBlocker` on the text edit's document as well as on the text edit itself before you start changing all the char formats. Because there may be some signals which are emitted after each individual change and cause needless refreshing... I do not say these will solve the issue, but it is worth trying. Anyway, `QSyntaxHighlighter` is designed exactly for your use case, you should give it a try.

Comment: Thx for the response. Did not know about QPlainTextEdit and yes I want to block all signals/events until the string formats are passed.